# Creating a table from .sql file in SQLite

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite

I'm just starting out in SQLite and have run into my first error.

What I'm trying to do is to create a table in my database with data from a text file, but I get these errors saying:

```
Error: near line 4: no such column: ’Microsoft’
Error: near line 5: no such column: ‘Apple’
Error: near line 6: no such column: ‘Youtube’
Error: near line 7: no such column: ‘Facebook’
```

My text file looks like this, I just manipulated a previously created table:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE stockprices (id integer primary key, price text);
INSERT INTO "stockprices" VALUES(22,’Microsoft’);
INSERT INTO "stockprices" VALUES(33,‘Apple’);
INSERT INTO "stockprices" VALUES(55, ‘Youtube’);
INSERT INTO "stockprices" VALUES(44, ‘Facebook’);
COMMIT;
```

And I get these errors by using the command:

```
.read ./Documents/sqlite3Files/stockprices.sql
```

I was under the impression that you could just create a new table from a already saved one?

Any suggestions on how to do this correctly would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors you see are because the quote you are using for string values are not what sqlite expects. You can try with " (ascii code 34) as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE stockprices (id integer primary key, price text);
INSERT INTO "stockprices" VALUES(22,"Microsoft");
INSERT INTO "stockprices" VALUES(33,"Apple");
INSERT INTO "stockprices" VALUES(55,"Youtube");
INSERT INTO "stockprices" VALUES(44,"Facebook");
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, strings must be quoted with single ASCII quotes (`'`).
Your .sql file contains typographic quotes (`‘`), probably because some word processor tried to be helpful.

Replace all `‘` with `'`.

<sup>(Note: Double quotes (`"`) should be used only for table/column names.)</sup>